# Schreibweise "Glück(s)schmerz"

Tags: spelling

Gibt es im Wort *Glück(**s**)schmerz* ein Fugen-s?

In den unten stehenden Links (1) und (2) wird kein Fugen-s verwendet:

(1) https://zwischen-den-fronten.net/2021/05/10/schadenfreude-und-glueckschmerz/

(2) https://www.psychologie-heute.de/leben/artikel-detailansicht/39895-das-pech-der-anderen.html

Dann fand ich dieses veröffentlichte Buch, das Korrektur gelesen wurde (hoffe ich mal), und hier setzt der Autor ein Fugen-s ein:

(3) https://repository.uinjkt.ac.id/dspace/bitstream/123456789/55568/1/Schaudenfreude%20%26%20Glucksschmerz.pdf

Heißt es nun *Glückschmerz* oder *Glück**s**schmerz*?

Vielen Dank!

PD: Der Word Korrekturmodus unterstreicht *Glückschmerz* rot...

Comment: Andere Komposita mit "Glück" nutzen das Fugen-s bevorzugt, aber auch die andere Variante: Glücksspiel / Glückspiel,  Glückssache / Glücksache.

Comment: Was soll das Wort überhaupt bedeuten? Der Link (1) sagt dazu: "so wird der eine oder Andere bereits richtig erahnt haben", was darauf hindeutet, dass das Wort nicht gebräuchlich ist, und etwas weiter wird dann auch erklärt, dass es dafür das gängige Wort "Neid" gibt.

Comment: @RalfFriedl: Soweit ich es verstanden habe, ist es das Gegenteil von "Schadenfreude". Man ist traurig, wenn es einem anderen gut geht (finanziell, karrieremäßig, familientechnisch etc.), und man es dem anderen nicht gönnt (und somit neidisch auf den anderen ist).

Comment: Was mich verwirrt ist, dass in (1) und (2) die Muttersprachler kein Fugen-s setzen, während der ausländische Autor in (3) "GlückSschmerz" schreibt. Wem soll man Glauben schenken?

Comment: Selbst wenn Fugen-s assimiliert werden dürfte in den dazu geneigten Dialekten (pure Behauptung), kann man dennoch von *underlying phoneme* reden (der deutsche Fachbegriff ist mir nicht bekannt), wenn man in der Regel von Akussativbildung ausgehen kann (seines Glückes Schmied, Freudentaumel, usw.). Dahingehend isr die Frage auch in Anbetracht des Tags (der Kategorie `spelling`) überhaupt nicht praezise genug—was ist "es"? Denn "Fugen-s" ist eher ein Begriff der Morphologie, Morphonologie. Die Orthographie ist dahingehend nichtmal sekundär (beweiskräftig) sonder schlicht irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

Da es sich bei *Glück(s)schmerz* um einen [Okkasionalismus](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/terminologie/4) handelt, ist die Bildung nicht festgelegt und keine der beiden Varianten kann als normativ falsch bezeichnet werden. Meines Erachtens gibt es aber ein starkes Argument, die Bildung mit Fugen-*s* zu bevorzugen: die Analogie. Komposita mit *Glück-* als Erstglied haben die *s*-Fuge:

> Glücksbringer, Glücksfall, Glücksfee, Glücksgefühl, Glücksgriff, Glückshormon, Glückskeks, Glückskind, Glücksmoment, Glückspilz, Glücksrad, Glücksspiel, Glückstag, Glückstreffer

Dagegen ohne Fugen-*s* nur *Glückwunsch* (und, in der Aussprache nur schwer zu unterscheiden, *Glücksache* neben *Glückssache*).

Bei der Variante ohne Fugen-*s* scheint es sich um ein englisches Wort zu handeln, dass der *Schadenfreude* gegenübergestellt wird als Schmerz, der empfunden wird, wenn es jemand anderem gutgeht. Im Englischen kann der Umlaut entfallen und auf Großschreibung verzichtet werden.

> Prior dislike leads to both *schadenfreude* and *gluckschmerz*. ([Schadenfreude and Gluckschmerz](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1754073918765657)).

Muttersprachler verwenden die Variante mit Fugenelement. Die Bedeutung ist hier nicht auf ein mögliches Pendant zu *Schadenfreude* beschränkt bzw. diese Bedeutung scheint überhaupt nicht vorzuliegen: es geht um ein schmerzhaftes Glück oder die gleichzeitige Präsenz von Schmerz und Glück.

> […] als die beiden […] sich endlich gegenüberstehen, prügeln sie von Glücksschmerz überwältigt aufeinander ein […] ([In den Fallen des Zufalls](https://magazin.spiegel.de/EpubDelivery/spiegel/pdf/9223953))
>
> […] i[n] […] dem akuten Glücksschmerz der Mütter beim Gebären. ([Wahrhaftig sein](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Wahrhaftig_sein/HZd4DwAAQBAJ))
>
> Bereits in diesem Begreifen liegt ein erstes Erfahrungsglück, ein Glücksschmerz und zugleich ein wohltuendes Schrumpfgefühl. ([Ein Glücksschmerz](https://www.heidelberg.de/hd/HD/Rathaus/Laudatio+Georg+Klein.html))

Comment: "Dagegen ohne Fugen-s nur Glückwunsch ..." Grimms Wörterbuch führt knapp über 100 Beispielwörter mit Fugen-s auf, darunter auch *Glückswunsch*, gegenüber **mehr als 700 ohne Fugen-s**. Deine Schlussfolgerung, Komposita mit *Glück-* würden bevorzugt mit Fugen-s gebildet, scheint mit deshalb falsch.

Comment: Die Analogie richtet sich nach dem lebendigen Sprachgebrauch: man orientiert sich an dem, was man präsent hat. Dazu gehört *Glückswunsch* nicht (und die anderen nicht genannten Belege ohne Fugenelement vermutlich auch nicht).

Comment: Barbara Hunfeld, Professorin für Literaturwissenschaft, verwendet "Glückswunsch" in ihrem 2009 veröffentlichten Buch *Hesperus*. Es gibt noch zahlreiche weitere jüngere Belege, in denen *Glückswunsch* die Bedeutung "Wunsch nach Glück (für sich selbst)" zu haben scheint, während *Glückwunsch* ja die Bedeutung "Wunsch an jemand anderen, dass er Glück haben möge" trägt. Es wäre echt toll, wenn du nicht wiederholt Dinge behaupten würdest, die ganz offensichtlich nicht stimmen (dass *Glückswunsch* nicht im Sprachgebrauch präsent sei, beispielsweise, oder es nur *Glückwunsch* ohne Fugen-s gebe).

Answer (score 1):

Wenn ich mit dem [Ngram-viewer von Google](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Gl%C3%BCckschmerz%2C+Gl%C3%BCcksschmerz&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=de-2019&smoothing=3) von 1800 bis 2019 nach den beiden deutschsprachigen Begriffen *"Glückschmerz, Glücksschmerz"* suche, werden mir nur Ergebnisse für *"Glücksschmerz"* angezeigt und es wird diese Meldung angezeigt:

> Ngrams not found: Glückschmerz

Das heißt nicht, dass dieses Wort niemals in einem Buch gedruckt wurde, aber es heißt, dass es in jenen Büchern, die Google bisher gescannt hat, so selten vorkommt, dass die wenigen Fundstellen, die es gab, als Fehler gewertet und bei der Datenbereinigung aus dem Korpus entfernt wurden.

Eine "normale" Suche mit Google zeigt mir diese Ergebnisse:

> "Glückschmerz": Ungefähr 7 740 Ergebnisse (0,45 Sekunden)
> "Glücksschmerz": Ungefähr 8 380 Ergebnisse (0,47 Sekunden)

Blättert man in den Suchergebnissen aber bis zur jeweils letzten Seite weiter, sieht es ganz anders aus:

> "Glückschmerz": Seite 12 von ungefähr 115 Ergebnissen (0,53 Sekunden)
> "Glücksschmerz": Seite 8 von ungefähr 71 Ergebnissen (0,44 Sekunden)

Betrachtet man die Fundstellen aber genauer, stellt man fest, das viele der Seiten, in denen das Wort "Glückschmerz" vorkommt, englischsprachige Seiten sind, in denen darüber diskutiert wird, wie dieses deutsche Wort ins Englische zu übersetzen ist. Die Seiten, die nicht englisch sind, sind französisch, finnisch, russisch usw. Deutschsprachige Seiten, in denen es nicht um sprachliche Besonderheiten des Wortes geht, sondern in denen es als Teil der "normalen" Konversation verwendet wird, gibt es fast gar keine.

Derselbe Befund gilt aber auch für "Glücksschmerz": Auch da findet man vor allem fremdsprachige Seiten, die sich mit sprachlichen Eigenheiten dieses Begriffs beschäftigen.

---

## Fazit:

Deutsche Muttersprachler verwenden weder das Wort *»Glücksschmerz«* noch das Wort *»Glückschmerz«*. Daher findet man auch beide Wörter nicht auf Wiktionary. Das DWDS hat zwar einen Dummy-Eintrag für [Glücksschmerz](https://www.dwds.de/?q=Gl%C3%BCcksschmerz&from=wb), aber nur 3 Belege für die Existenz dieses Wortes. Für [Glückschmerz](https://www.dwds.de/?q=Gl%C3%BCckschmerz&from=wb) gibt es auch einen Dummy-Eintrag (weil die Seite on the fly für jedes Kompositum einen Dummy-Eintrag erzeugt) aber mit 0 Belegen.

Allerdings scheint es unter Personen, die Deutsch als Fremdsprache lernen, das Gerücht zu geben, diese Wörter würden von deutschen Muttersprachlern verwendet werden. Und weil in diesem Personenkreis offenbar viel über die Existenz dieser Wörter diskutiert wird, gibt es nun diese Wörter.

---

#### Aber welcher Fugenlaut ist nun der richtige?

Hier darf man frei wählen. Strenge Regeln für Fugenlaute gibt es nicht, daher gibt es auch viele regionale Unterschiede ("Adventskalender" und "Zugverspätung" in Deutschland, aber "Adventkalender" und "Zugsverspätung" in Österreich). In der Praxis gilt bei einem Kompositum jener Laut als richtig, der in der Gemeinschaft der in der Nähe lebenden Muttersprachler am häufigsten verwendet wird. Nachdem aber beide Wörter von keinem Muttersprachler verwendet werden, bleibt auch die normative Kraft des Faktischen auf der Strecke, weil es nichts Faktisches gibt. Daher: Beides ist gleich richtig.

Answer (score 0):

Die Google-Buchsuche findet 84 Belege für *Glückschmerz* und 40 für *Glücksschmerz*. Die Google-Suche findet 768 Belege für *Glückschmerz* und 428 für *Glücksschmerz*. Die Form ohne Fugen-s scheint also geringfügig häufiger verwendet zu werden. Insgesamt ist das Wort aber zu selten, um aus diesen Häufigkeiten – oder vielmehr Seltenheiten – einen verlässlichen Schluss zu ziehen.

Demgegenüber gibt es beispielsweise für *Glückkeks* 6670 Belege im Internet gegenüber 226000 für *Glückskeks*. Hier kann man klar davon ausgehen, dass die Schreibung mit Fugen-s die gewöhnliche ist. Da das Internet auch Belege für klare Falschschreibungen wie *[Blaubere](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Blaubere%22)* findet (und zwar 6440), können wir vermuten, dass die knapp siebentausend Belege für *Glückkeks* ebenfalls Falschschreibungen sind.

Die Seltenheit von *Glück(s)schmerz* spricht m.E. dafür, dass es das Wort nicht gibt und es sich bei den Befunden jeweils um poetische Spontanbildungen handelt, für die dementsprechend noch keine Normalisierung der Schreibweise stattgefunden hat. Das heißt, beide Formen sind bislang gleichermaßen "richtig".

Comment: Auf Googles Mengenangabe ist kein Verlass. Daher ist die Schlussfolgerung bzgl. "Seltenheit" nicht tragbar. Denn man braucht nicht bestreiten, das 400 Belege durchaus sinnvoll wären, wenn die Antwort die Belege nicht Ansatzweise auszuwerten versucht.

Comment: @vectory "Auf Googles Mengenangabe ist kein Verlass." Natürlich nicht. Es gibt aber auch keine bessere Quelle. Der tatsächliche Sprachgebrauch lässt sich nicht belegen, denn dafür müsste man alles was alle Menschen jemals gesagt oder geschrieben haben, auswerten. In der Wissenschaft ist es deshalb üblich, eine Teilstichprobe (z.B. alle von Google gescannten Bücher oder Webseiten) der Grundgesamtheit (alles jemals Geschriebene und Gesagte) zu erheben. Dafür ist Google m.W. die beste Quelle. Oder welche wäre (und warum) besser?

Comment: Und selbst wenn Google nur einen Teil des Sprachgebrauchs abbildet und dabei einen Bias hat, betrifft dies ja nicht nur *Glück(s)schmerz* sondern jedes Wort, so dass sich vielleicht keine absoluten Angaben über *Glück(s)schmerz* machen lassen, aber ein Vergleich mit der Häufigkeit anderer Wörter möglich ist (die ja  derselben Selektion) unterliegen. Und das ist ein Vergleich, den ich sehr wohl vorgenommen habe (mit *Glück(s)keks* und *Blaube(e)re*). Das ist dasselbe Vorgehen, wie bei Umfragen, wenn man annimmt, dass die Verteilung in der Stichprobe der in der Grundgesamtheit entspricht.

Comment: Oder wie in der Meteorologie, wenn man nur Messungen an einzelnen Messpunkten vornimmt und nicht den Zustand jedes Moleküls in der Atmosphäre kennt.

Comment: Führe dir vielleicht mal ein Buch zu Gemüte, sowas wie "Korpora in der germanistischen Sprachwissenschaft" (Leibniz-Institut für Deutsche Sprache). Bitte erstatte darüber Bericht, wie's war. Auszugsweise ein paar Seiten lesen dürfte der "Meteorologie" Methode entsprechend ausreichen. Übrigens hat ids-mannheim COSMAS II als *Online-Zugriff auf das Deutsche Referenzkorpus DeReKo* im Angebot (mit Anmeldung).